# Trouble installing Pokerstars on a Live USB without Persistence through WINE

Tags: system-installation, live-environment

I need to install any form of Texas Hold Em' on a Lubuntu Live USB that doesn't have persistence.

I was able to download PokerStars.net by emulating the .exe (a windows type file) using WINE for Linux (Lubuntu). But, when I try to install, I have no room. The only place on the Live USB is in the root folder which is set to read-only.

Is there any way I can change the read only properties of the Live USB while it's in use?

So, to recap. I am running Lubuntu 13.04 and can't start in Persistent mode. When I start normally everything worked fine. I proceeded to Chromium and successfully downloaded Wine and the Pokerstars.exe. I right clicked the downloaded fiel then clicked Wine, the installer loaded fine. There are about 8 different disk icons and only the one containing system files is active.

Is there any way I can use the terminal to install it to Root.

Comment: You first have to make your USB writeable installing it into an USB. Otherwise, no attemp will be valid. About editing questions please read: http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/7319/169736

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way I can change the read only properties of the Live USB while it's in use?

No. You copied Ubuntu in a read-only fashion into your drive. While is read-only, all the changes will be lost. That you have already noticed when you try to install stuff into the drive.

> So, to recap. I am running Lubuntu 13.04 and can't start in Persistent mode.

Then change it to persisten mode or use the method to [install Ubuntu into the USB](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key-without-using-startup-disk-creator). Otherwise you will be into a standstill.

> I right clicked the downloaded fiel then clicked Wine, the installer loaded fine. There are about 8 different disk icons and only the one containing system files is active.

Good, seems that WINE will not be a problem once you have installed Ubuntu **into** the USB.

> Is there any way I can use the terminal to install it to Root.

Is a read-only filesystem, until you make it read-write as I mentioned above, there is no way to do so.

> without having to buy another USB to install it to

You can use your already created drive.

Comment: OK, I used LinuxLiveUSB to download and install Lubuntu on the Drive. Is there a different more recommended program that has been known to get the persistence working properly? (preferably without a lot of technical steps)

Comment: [Please, read the link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key-without-using-startup-disk-creator), I'm only trying to guide you and your current status is a no-go.